# Rails console tips, tricks and customizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, irb

There's this great post on [irb tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123494/whats-your-favourite-irb-trick), but what about further customizing Rails console behavior and output?

[Awesome print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) and [Hirb](http://tagaholic.me/hirb/) are great.

SQL logging  is a must for me. In your `~/.irbrc` paste:

```
require 'logger'
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined?(Rails)
```

What's your tip/trick/gem of choice?

Comment: irb link appears to have been deleted. However I think https://github.com/pry/pry has a lot to offer and probably won't evaporate anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently written a rails specific console tweaks blog post: https://rbjl.janlelis.com/49-railsrc-rails-console-snippets (as [gist](https://gist.github.com/896750))

Answer (score 0):

Open last migration in your editor quickly!  Assuming you already open your editor with a command like `atom .` to open the project root in atom, you can do:

```
atom $(echo "db/migrate/$(ls db/migrate | tail -1)")
```

Of course you can replace `atom` with `subl` etc. You can easily alias this to a function. I keep things like this in `~/.functions` which load in my shell.

```
last_migration() {
        atom $(echo "db/migrate/$(ls db/migrate | tail -1)")
}
```

Then you can later create migrations and open them in 1 go:

```
rails g migration create_some_migration_name && last_migration
```