# WEBrick log to console like in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, server, webrick

Currently running: `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails s`

The console has zero output (it logs to staging.log just fine). I'd like to get a console output just like `development` mode or if I ran `bundle exec rails s`.

**EDIT**

Found this, no answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101692/how-to-show-log-on-webrick-console-under-production-mode

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get all of the logging output into the console but you can definitely get the SQL log output - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774847/rails-console-tips-tricks-and-customizations